# Maven with Jacoco and Sonar 0% coverage

Tags: scala, maven, sonarqube, scalatest, jacoco

I have a scala project (with a few java files) built using maven (scala-maven-plugin). We have jacoco plugged in for code coverage (jacoco-maven-plugin) and that generates good-ish scala code coverage. We can see the html / csv reports in the typical place in /target and the scala coverage is all there and good.

However we cannot get the code coverage with sonar to work on the scala files. The plugin runs and it sends the java coverage so I know it's picking up something from the jacoco output, but the scala coverage is missing.

In addition if I run the jacoco:check goal as part of the build, it fails on the coverage, again citing only java coverage as the total coverage figure. This leads me to believe the problem is something to do with the way I've configured jacoco not with sonar.

Any help appreciated.

Here are the relevant parts of the pom

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-g:vars</arg>
                    </args>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.2.201302030002</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
           <!-- disable surefire -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.plugin.surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- enable scalatest -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-M2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                            <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                            <parallel>true</parallel>
                            <tagsToExclude>IntegrationTest</tagsToExclude>
                            <filereports>ScalaTestSuite.txt</filereports>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                            <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                            <parallel>true</parallel>
                            <tagsToInclude>IntegrationTest</tagsToInclude>
                            <filereports>ScalaIntegrationTestSuite.txt</filereports>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven3-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
            </plugin>




  <sonar.host.url>http://vltapp02:9000/</sonar.host.url>
    <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:h2:tcp://vltapp02:9092/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.surefire.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: In the end I wrote https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage

Answer (score 0):

May be jacoco/sonar check against source folders. In this case you should try to expose the scala source folder to other plugins (via 'add-source' goal):

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-g:vars</arg>
                </args>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I still get the same issues. 
[INFO] [09:57:45.824] Analysing C:\development\workspace\mpp\mpp-buster\target\jacoco.exec
[WARN] [09:57:45.926] Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include debug information into compiled classes?

Comment: @monkjack So compile in debug mode, like the warning informs